# RxJava- performing a peek() or void operation within an Observable chain?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Java 8 lambda streams have a `peek()` operator which allows you to execute a void operation on each item. This is typically used for debugging, but it also is a nice way to cheat and kick off a void  operation without mapping to something.

Is there an equivalent to this in RxJava? Maybe I'm not following a good practice or thinking reactively enough... but it would be really handy to create status labels before and after an operation? If `peek()` is not supported, is there a better pattern to follow?

```
Observable<Item> Item= ...;

Label statusLabel = new Label();
Label resultLabel = new Label();

Observable<CalculatedItem> calculatedItem = calculated.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.peek(c -> statusLabel.setText("Working.."))
.map(c -> performExpensiveCalculation(c))
.peek(r -> statusLabel.setText(""));

calculatedItem.subscribe(c -> resultLabel.setText(c));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a method `doOnNext(Action1<Item> action)` that will be called for each item in the stream.

[Documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html)